# Data structure inside an object in Python

Tags: python, class, object, data-structures

I know you can do, for example:

```
class Node(object):
   __slots__ = 'data', 'left', 'right'

   def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
      self.data  = data
      self.left  = left
      self.right = right
```

But how can I do something in order to get, for example:

```
class Node(object):
   __slots__ = 'data', 'left', 'right'
   data.struct = 'hour', 'min', 'day'

   def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
      self.data  = data
      self.left  = left
      self.right = right
      self.data.hour = hour
      self.data.min = min
      self.data.day = day
```

I know that syntax is not right, but I hope you can get the idea.

Comment: Please elaborate. Your question is _really_ unclear. Are you talking about variable assignment? Are you talking about default values? Are you talking about initialization methods?... Please explain. Possibly with more code. :)

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll edit.

Comment: There are no parameters named hour, min and day. If they existed, assigning self.data would be redundant with assigning self.data.hour, self.data.min and self.data.day. Please fix the pseudocode and explain your intent.

Comment: I'm sorry. If I'm doing this with pseudocode is because I don't know how to do it properly. That is why I'm asking for help.

I think the idea is pretty clear: I want to have and object with fields 'data', 'left' and 'right', and I want to have in the 'data' field some structure with fields 'hour', 'min' and 'day'.

Sorry if I don't explain myself correctly and thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define class for `data`, that contains members `hours, min, day`. You can use it convenient factory `collections.namedtuple` for basic use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections

Time_tuple = collections.namedtuple("Time", ['hour', 'min', 'day'])


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, time=(None, None, None)):
        self.time = Time_tuple(*time)

node = Node()
print repr(node.time.day)

other_node = Node((23, 50, 1))
print other_node.time.hour
```

Please note, that this gives you no control about if values passed to constructor are valid. If you would like to add check like this, you should write your own `Time_tuple` class, and raise `ValueError` if data is incorrect (e.g. hour is `42`).

- see https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. But one more question: how can I update just one field? I mean, I can't do: `self.time.dia = r`. Any clue?

Comment: tuples are immutable, so you cannot change only part of it. You may create new tuple and assign it. You can unpack tuple: `hour, min, day = node.time`, change one part: `day = new_day` and assign a new one: `node.time = Time_tuple(hour, min, day)`. Or just write your own class with members, as I mentioned earlier.